# Integral of the error function

Tags: calculus, error-function

So I know that 
$$\displaystyle \int_{0}^{\infty} \text{erf}(x) dx$$
does not converge 
so I am assuming that 
$$\displaystyle \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\text{erf}(x)}{x} dx$$ does not converge? Is there anyway to estimate these integrals?

By the way I arrived at that equation from the following:

$$\displaystyle \int_{0}^{p} \frac{\text{exp}(-r^2)r^2}{p} dr \approx \frac{\text{erf}(p)}{p}$$

so maybe my evaluation of that integral is wrong? Thanks for the help guys!

Comment: $$\int_0^{\infty} dx \operatorname{erfc}{x} = \frac1{\sqrt{\pi}} $$

Comment: erf is essentially the constant $1$ for large $x.$ So the integrand in your second integral is larger than $1/(2x)$ and the integral larger than $(1/2) \log N$ where the integral is from $1$  out to $N$

Comment: @RonGordon Wait i'm confused... wolfram alpha seems to think that does not converge http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integral+of+erf%28x%29+dx+from+x%3D0+to+infinity

Comment: @user2879934: It converges.  Integrate by parts.  Think for yourself, don't substitute common sense with Dr. Wolfram's robot.

Comment: Oh my question was about erf not erfc sorry!

Comment: @user2879934: yes, but the point is that the relationship between erf and erfc should give you insight into how the integral over erf diverges.

Answer (score 1):

If $f$ is pdf of a standard normal ($f'=-xf$), integration by parts yields:

$$I(a,b)=\int_{a}^{b} r^2f(r)\,dr = \Phi(b)-\Phi(a)+af(a)-bf(b)$$

For $a=0$ and $b$ large we get asymptotics:
$$I(0,p)\approx\frac 1 2-(b+\frac 1 b)f(b)\approx \frac 1 2-bf(b)$$
You can translate the above into your integral.

Answer (score 0):

Since:
$$
\text{erf}(x)=\int_0^x\frac{2}{\sqrt{\pi}}\exp\left(-y^2\right)\mathrm{d}y
$$
Thus, since all the functions are non-negative, we can change the order of integration - take care of the change of the integration limits (due to Fubini):
$$
\displaystyle \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\text{erf}(x)}{x}\mathrm{d}x=\int_0^\infty\int_{0}^x\frac{2}{\sqrt{\pi}x}e^{-y^2}\mathrm{d}y\mathrm{d}x=\int_{0}^\infty\int_{y}^\infty \frac{2}{\sqrt{\pi}x}e^{-y^2}\mathrm{d}x\mathrm{d}y
$$
And the inner integral does not converge for any $y$.

Comment: Thanks Akos! Is there any way to approximate that reliably? Or if not is there any way to solve the last integral in my question without erf?